# Laptops connected to 2.4GHz network cannot access printer

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, printer

I have a dual-band router with several laptops and two printers connected to it. Most laptops use 5GHz, while the printers and a couple older laptops use 2.4GHz. All laptops in the 5GHz can connect to printers no problem, but none of the laptops in 2.4GHz can even ping the printers.

All the 2.4GHz laptops are identical, running Win 8.1.

What settings can I try to adjust in the router / the laptops to fix this?

EDIT: I tried joining the 2.4GHz on one of the laptops that also operate in 5GHz. I can't connect to printers when I join the lower bandwidth network, so culprit must be settings on the router.

Comment: Maybe some "wireless isolation" or "guest network" setting on the 2.4GHz network? Without knowing what router or seeing a screenshot of what settings you have it is difficult to suggest anything as many routers have different settings available.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the tip. Right now I don't have access to the router, it's managed by somebody else. I'll try to post some screenshots later.

Comment: Some other questions that could do with being in your question: how is the printer connected to the router? If it is wireless then which network is it on? Can it be moved to a wired connection? Can the 2.4GHz users talk to each other? Can 2.4GHz users talk to the 5GHz users? (file sharing or some other local-only networking software, not any internet based disovery solutions)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Everything is using wireless connections. Printers are on the 2.4GHz, sorry if the question wasn't clear on that. Laptops in 2.4GHz can't ping laptops in 5GHz network, but they can find each other. I ordered some USB dongles to connect all laptops to 5GHz, hoping this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using WiFi, all partners which communicates together "on the air" have to use exactly the same channel, i.e. the same band too.

You have mentioned a router. I suspect that it has WiFi ports as well as hard wired ports. Are the printers connected to the hard wired ports ? If you connect to the printer via a router, there are two communication path: The one between your computer to the router and another one between the router and the printer. Be sure that you have configured your computer to communicate to the printer via the router. Of course, the communication between the printer and the router has to be configured well too.

Comment: A "good" router would bridge the wired, 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks so that they are essentially one single network to computers working on it. Old routers isolated the various networks but for home use with discoverable Tv's, computers and tablets this is much less desirable now. Newer routers should be able to choose to isolate bands or networks for "guest" access to the internet but that would normally be done by ssid rather than frequency band.

Comment: A lot of this answer also reads like a comment or query. You've recently gained the reputation to comment so you should be using that rather than asking questions in your answer.